# merge pieces of file together

Tags: linux, script, find, sed, bash-scripting

I have a directory tree of files I need to loop through and reformat the lines.  can I do this with **sed** with some combination of **find**?

for each file, I'll need to adjust the text in the file from

```
...
* @category Foo
* @package Bar
...
```

into just this (Remove the @category line, but prepend the value to the package annotation value)

```
...
* @package Foo/Bar
...
```

what is the most efficient way of doing this?  its a few hundred files that will be modified.

Comment: I don't know how to use sed, but if you are able to write a bash script, which does this operation for one file, you can do it for every file in the directory tree by using "find ./ -exec bash-script {} \;"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed '/@category/{s/.*@category /* @package /;N;s/\n.*@package /\//}'
```

To run this against all the files in a whole tree, I would do something like this:

```
for i in $(find . -type f); do
   sed '/@category/{s/.*@category /* @package /;N;s/\n.*@package /\//}' $i > $i.new
   mv $i.new $i
done
```

Comment: Nice work.  But since he's using Linux (GNU sed), why wouldn't you use **sed -i** to replace inline, and do away with the loop using **find -type f -exec sed -i ... {} +** ?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.  Largely a matter of taste.  But that is a non-standard extension and that bit of knowledge about `sed` is less generally useful than knowing how to use a `for` loop.  Also, explicitly looping also gives you the chance, if you want, to modify the behavior to preview what will happen (by removing the `mv` statement) or undo it (if you add a `mv $i $i.old`).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -ri '$!N;s/^\* @category (.*)\n(\* @package )(.*)/\2\1\/\3/;P;D' {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

When you have to work on multiple lines, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) comes in mind, it's more suitable than `sed` to do this.

```
awk '/^\* +@package/{print $0"/"v;next} {if ($0 ~ /^\* +@category/){v=$3}else{print}}' file.txt
```

Or decomposed :

```
awk '
    /^\* +@package/{
        print $0"/"v
        next
    }
    {
        if ($0 ~ /^\* +@category/){
            v=$3
        }
        else{
            print
        }
    }
' file.txt
```

Comment: One True awk :)